# How can I start caffeine in active mode?

Tags: 14.04

I want caffeine 2.8.3 to be active as soon as it starts up. To achieve this I thought there would be a cli option, but the help page `caffeine -h` does not revel any hints.

How can I start caffeine in active mode?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, not elegant, but it works for what you want.

```
caffeinate sleep 9999999
```

`caffeinate` will keep the computer await until the next command finishes. In this case, it will keep your computer up for just under 116 days or until you logout or shutdown.

`caffeine` itself is primarily for when programs run full-screen. It will prevent sleeping the entire time that program is in full-screen. `caffeinate` was designed to be run for other programs you don't want to be interrupted (such as a big update, non-full-screen game, or something like that).

Although there is probably some way to activate the caffeine indicator automatically, this is the best I can do for the time being.

Also, if you want to kill it to allow sleeping at any time, run `pkill caffeinate`.

You could also just change your computer settings to never sleep/darken screen/screensaver at all, then you don't need to worry about it.