# Ubuntu 20.04.1 / Caffeine Indicator does not appear in status bar

Tags: gnome, 20.04, wayland, caffeine

I recently updated from Ubuntu 18.04.4 to 20.04.1. Although *Caffeine Indicator* is listed in the *Startup Applications* ...

[image: Screenshot of Startup Applications]

... it does **not** automatically appear in the top status bar after I log-in. This worked in the former Ubuntu version.
Is there something I can do about it?

## Environment

- Caffeine Indicator version: 2.9.4
- Window manager: Gnome 3.36.3
- Desktop environment: ubuntu-wayland
- Linux distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.1

## Analysis

Starting the application from the shell produces the following output:

```
$ caffeine-indicator 
/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator:184: PyGIDeprecationWarning: Since version 3.11,
    calling threads_init is no longer needed. 
    See: https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/Threading
  GObject.threads_init()
/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator:106: DeprecationWarning: 
    AyatanaAppIndicator3.Indicator.set_icon is deprecated
  self.AppInd.set_icon(icon_name)
```

When I activate it then this is output:

```
INFO:root:caffeine-indicator is inhibiting desktop idleness
```

## Related

- [Trusty: Caffeine doesn't appear in panel after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469225/trusty-caffeine-doesnt-appear-in-panel-after-update?rq=1)
- [How can I start caffeine in active mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814813/how-can-i-start-caffeine-in-active-mode)

Comment: Is there any error if you launch it `caffeine-indicator` in terminal, Does it show up in indicator?

Comment: @user.dz I added the output to my post. No error, though.

Comment: I get the same output from the terminal, and caffeine works fine, so that's not a part of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `caffeine` package includes three commands: `caffeine`,`caffeinate` and `caffeine-indicator`.

The `caffeine` is what is responsible for preventing idle, but it only runs in the background. You need to run the `caffeine-indicator` to control it form topbar.

Having both of those in the startup apps (one entry for `/usr/bin/caffeine` and one for `/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator`) works for me.

---

I'm on 20.04 and I've installed caffeine 2.9.4-2 using `sudo apt install caffeine` (the same as apt-get, btw)

Comment: I manually added an entry for `/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator` to the startup applications, restarted, then the entry for `/usr/bin/caffeine` was gone. I manually added it back, restarted, both entries stayed. - Both times the caffeine-indicator did **not** show up in the topbar.

Comment: check if the processes for caffeine are present even though the indicator is not visible.

Something such as `pstree | grep -C 500 caffeine` shows the full tree with the processes highlighted.

This should help identify whether it's the caffeine malfunctioning, or if it's the "run on startup" malfunctioning.

Comment: There is no output from `pstree | grep -C 500 caffeine` or `pstree | grep caffeine`.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a problem of the version of caffeine you have. Something is blocking it from launching or is killing it.

Try running it from a terminal (and sending it to the background)
`caffeine & caffeine-indiator&`

Does it appear on the pstree then?

Comment: Yes, it does. - Meanwhile, the indicator appeared by itself at some of the startups of the machine. On other times it did not.

Comment: None of those commands work on Ubuntu 20.04 for me. Like op said, the problem seems to be that the icon isn't showing, not that it isn't running.

Answer (score 2):

press `Super` and type `extensions`, then find caffeine there and go to its `setting` and enable `show on top panel`

Comment: Caffeine is not listed in *Extensions*.

Comment: How you installed caffeine?

Comment: Via `sudo apt-get install caffeine`.

Comment: just remove it via `sudo apt-get autoremove caffeine` go to [caffeline extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/)  and apply it simple :))

Comment: This worked for me. TL;DR purge the buggy non-working system package and install the Gnome extension.